# Multiple legacy GPUs drivers problems

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, display-driver

I have two AMD GPUs, [HD4xxx](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2064) and [HD5xxx](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%208.1%20-%2064) series, running without CrossFire. After installing the second one (HD5xxx), drivers were added to Windows automatically, then, after reinstalling legacy drivers everything worked on HD4xxx, and HD5xxx was capable of displaying windows in native resolution.

I tried to test both cards to see which one is better (performance wise), so i used AMD Clean, then installed HD5x drivers, AMD Clean, then HD4x.

Now i'm having troubles going back to HD4x running on it's legacy drivers 1, and second one running on Windows default WDDM. I can't find anywhere the option to re-download the defaults (probably Windows Update drivers). **Is that an option somewhere?** I tried the Windows Update catalog but neither of drivers there worked. With every drivers, trying to install HD4x legacy, then manually selecting .inf in Device Manager doesn't give me connection to drivers in Catalyst), and Direct3d doesn't work in `dxdiag`, neither VLC (all three are crashing). **Is there a better option of handling multiple legacy drivers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't find anywhere the option to re-download the defaults (probably Windows Update drivers).  **Is that an option somewhere?**

You need to re-enable automatic driver updates (set `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching\SearchOrderConfig` to 1), then uninstall driver with software in Device Manager and search automatically for updated driver software.